# Android cannot find method from JAR on runtime

Tags: java, android, jar, android-studio

I've been working on an app that uses AES encryption which requires a JAR for Base 64 encoding and decoding.

I followed this tutorial [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dpuJPoXkFG4) on importing a JAR (could be my issue since seems like they have no idea what they are doing). The line by line compilation is happy but upon runtime on the phone I get the error message

```
 Could not find method org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.decodeBase64, referenced from method com.login.tools.Encoder.decrypt
```

My Application gradle script does have reference to the JAR

```
compile project(':commons-codec-1.10')
```

Which should call the commons-codec-1.10 gradle script

```
configurations.create("default")
artifacts.add("default", file('commons-codec-1.10.jar'))
```

The calling class itself looks a bit like

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
.
.
.
public static String decrypt(String strToDecrypt)
    setDecryptedString(new String(cipher.doFinal(Base64.decodeBase64(strToDecrypt))));
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use Gradle dependencies, not a `.jar`:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.10'
}
```

See: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.10

Also, I see your are trying to use `org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.decodeBase6`. Android has it's own Base64 library:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64.html

Comment: Awesome thanks! I actually decided to ditch the JAR as the Android Base64 library works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem. But this solution work for me. Hope it help's you.

If you want to decrypt the string, then use below code. You can also use

> android.util.Base64

rather than

> org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64

```
package com.myApp.security;

import  android.util.Base64;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

public class Security {
    public static String encrypt(String input, String key){
      byte[] crypted = null;
      try{
        SecretKeySpec skey = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), "AES");
          Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
          cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skey);
          crypted = cipher.doFinal(input.getBytes());
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }
        return new String(Base64.encode(crypted, Base64.DEFAULT));
    }

    public static String decrypt(String input, String key){
        byte[] output = null;
        try{
          SecretKeySpec skey = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), "AES");
          Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
          cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skey);
          //output = cipher.doFinal(Base64.decodeBase64(input));
          output = cipher.doFinal(Base64.decode(input, Base64.DEFAULT));
        }catch(Exception e){
          System.out.println(e.toString());
        }
        return new String(output);
    }   
}
```

Use these encrypt & decrypt methods in to your class directly.

```
String key = "Dhruv349emaeGtuL";
String data = "example";
Log.e("Decrypt_Key", Security.decrypt(Security.encrypt(data, key), key));
Log.e("Encrypted Data", Security.encrypt(data, key));
```